# GXT combobox trigger not firing in IE-8

Tags: combobox, gxt

I am having issues with the Combo box/Simple Combo box trigger field not loading store data on first trigger click in IE-8.Needs a second click to populate the drop down list. Firefox doesn't have this problem and works as desired(loads data on first click). Anyone aware of this issue or how resolve it?

`SimpleComboBox<String> stateComboBox = new SimpleComboBox<String>()`
`stateComboBox.setEmptyText("Select");
        stateComboBox.setTypeAhead(true);
        stateComboBox.setId("state");
        stateComboBox.setItemId("state");
        stateComboBox.setForceSelection(true);
        stateComboBox.setWidth(65);
        stateComboBox.setAllowBlank(false);
        stateComboBox.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
        stateComboBox.setQueryDelay(0);`

Comment: SimpleComboBox gxt will work properly on ie also.did u specify user-agent property in config.gwt.xml

Comment: @swamy: thanks for the response. I have the user-agent property commented out since we support multiple browsers.Also this issue happens only in IE-8, IE-9 works as desired.